# Subscribing to Microsoft Word COM events

Tags: c#, dynamic-typing, word-automation

I'm writing code to access the MS Word automation COM interface using dynamic types in C# 4.0. It works great and it is very easy to use.

What I don't know is how to subscribe events. I would like to subscribe to the [Application::Quit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationevents4_event.quit.aspx) event.

This is the code I have written:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Type wordType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");
        dynamic word = Activator.CreateInstance(wordType);

        var myDoc = word.Documents.Open(@"C:\example.docx");
        word.Visible = true;

        //how can I subscribe to the word.Quit event??
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event)word).Quit += OnQuit;
```

...and then...

```
private void OnQuit()
{
     MessageBox.Show("Quit");
}
```

Comment: Note that I have not a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, I'm using COM directly.